# Local apache cannot resolve vhosts

Tags: apache, vhosts

I've set up an local Apache (2.4.33) with Homebrew on my Mac (macOS 10.13.5). The server is running and the syntax check for configuration files  returns "Syntax OK".
I've defined a couple of Virtual Hosts for my DEV environments in the httpd-vhosts.conf file (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf) and checked if this file is actually loaded:

```
httpd -D DUMP_INCLUDES
Included configuration files:
(*) /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
(542) /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I did another check to assure if the Vhost configuration is OK, too:

```
httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40)
     port 80 namevhost localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40)
     port 80 namevhost spielwiese.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:45)
     port 80 namevhost phpmyadmin.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:77)
     port 80 namevhost relaunch.domain1.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:85)
     port 80 namevhost dev.domain2.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:93)
     port 80 namevhost test.domain2.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:101)
```

This looks promising so far. Strangely enough all vhosts but two (dev.domain2.local & test.domain2.local) can be resolved and I can't find the error in my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/phpmyadmin"
ServerName phpmyadmin.local
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.local-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/owncloud/somefolder/www/relaunch.domain1.local/public_html"
ServerName relaunch.domain1.local
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/relaunch.domain1.local-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/relaunch.domain1.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/dev.domain2.local/web"
ServerName dev.domain2.local
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dev.domain2.local-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dev.domain2.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/test.domain2.local"
ServerName test.domain2.local
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.domain2.local-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.domain2.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I've stopped, started and restarted the apache multiple times, but always get the same result:

```
$ ping phpmyadmin.local
PING phpmyadmin.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
$ ping test.domain2.local
ping: cannot resolve test.domain2.local: Unknown host
$ ping dev.domain2.local
ping: cannot resolve dev.domain2.local: Unknown host
```

Any ideas or hints how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you pointed those 2 domains to 127.0.0.1 in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: THANK YOU for the hint, @dusan-bajic - this solved my problem! I haven´t found the hosts file, because I was looking in usr/local/etc, the folder where the configuration files (httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf) are located.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - thanks to @dusan-bajic! After adding those two domains to the /etc/hosts file everything works as expected.